# Sending key presses to elements

Tags: r, selenium

I try to run the example from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html)

In firefox using firebug for google write box I can see this to find the id:

```
<input id="gs_htif0" class="gsfi" disabled="" autocomplete="off" aria-hidden="true" style="border: medium none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: auto; width: 100%; position: absolute; z-index: 1; background-color: transparent; color: silver; transition: all 0.218s ease 0s; opacity: 0; text-align: left; left: 0px;" dir="ltr">
```

Using the following code:

```
library("RSelenium")
startServer()
checkForServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.google.com/")
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//*/input[@id = 'gs_htif0']")
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list("R Cran", "\uE007"))
```

The error I receive is the following:

```
Error:   Summary: InvalidElementState
     Detail: An element command could not be completed because the element is in an invalid state (e.g. attempting to click a disabled element).
     class: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException
```

Comment: Google search box correct xpath is `//*[@id="lst-ib"]` , May be you are using incorrect.

Comment: @HelpingHands that's right. If you want please put it as an answer to mark it?

Comment: Great , I just put as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have used incorrect xpath , Correct xpath for google search box is `//*[@id="lst-ib"]`

Hope it will solve your issue.